# preg_replace with two replacments

Tags: php, regex

I have a sentence in the DB for example:

```
His $name$ is $Luis$
```

Now, I want to replace the $..$ in tags (< b >), for something like:

```
His <b>name</b> is <b>Luis</b>
```

How can I do it with preg_replace? I tried to do simply:

```
$replace[0] = '<b>';
$replace[1] = '</b>';
preg_replace('/[$]/', $replace, $string);
```

But doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace( '/\$(.*?)\$/', '<b>\1</b>', $string );
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
$source = 'His $name$ is $Luis$';
$result = preg_replace('/\$(.*?)\$/', '<b>$1</b>', $source);
```